# Overriding the href img src value in an ImageField in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm uploading certain media to a particular directory to secure it. The images are uploaded using an inlineformset_factory object.

The problem I have is that where viewing the uploaded record in the admin site it appears to prepend my settings.MEDIA_URL (/media/) to the path of the uploaded image.

ie.

```
http://localhost:8000/media/<relative image path>
```

What I would like it to use instead is a custom setting, settings.PROTECTED_MEDIA_URL ('src') to return the following path instead:

```
http://localhost:8000/scr/<relative image path>
```

Included below are what I believe are the relevant parts of the code.

Any insight is appreciated!

settings.py

```
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
PROTECTED_MEDIA_URL = '/scr/'
...
```

model.py

```
...
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
fs = FileSystemStorage(location = '/home/user/nginx_restricted')

def orig_car_id_folder(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/images/orig/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.car_id, filename)

class OwnersCar(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...

class OwnersCarImages(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(OwnersCar)
    orig_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=orig_car_id_folder,
        verbose_name='Upload Image',
        storage=fs
    )
    ...
...
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from vehicle_admin_ac.models import OwnersCar, OwnersCarImages

class CarImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OwnersCarImages
    exclude = ('thumbnail',)

class OwnersCarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('owner','brand',)
    ordering = ('owner',)
    search_fields = ('owner',)
    inlines = [
        CarImageInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(OwnersCar, OwnersCarAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^scr/(?P<protected_image_path>/uploads/images/(thumb|orig)/.*)$',
        'vehicle_admin_ac.views.protected_view',
        name='protected_view'),
    ...
)
...
```

views.py

```
...
@login_required
def protected_view(request, protected_image_path):
    response = HttpResponse()
    url = protected_image_path
    response['Content-Type']=""
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/protected/{0}".format(url)
    return response

@login_required
def add_vehicle(request):
    ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(OwnersCar, OwnersCarImages, form=InitialCarImageForm, extra=3)
    owners_car = OwnersCar()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.OwnersCarForm(request.POST, instance=owners_car)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=owners_car)
        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            new_car = form.save(commit=False)
            new_car.owner = request.user
            new_car.save()
            formset.save()  # save() method works fine with 'inlineformset_factory'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(new_car.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = forms.OwnersCarForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet()
    return render_to_response('add_new.html',
        {'form': form, 'formset': formset},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
...
```

Comment: Gah, just read about the base_url as a FileSystemStorage argument in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class). I set base_url='/src/' and the image is handled fine.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class) the relevant part of the docs that I'd missed, explaining the base_url argument.